# Map Infowindow not loading

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a working map that loads markers based on an ajax call and some other options as seen below, now I'm trying to add an infowindow to each marker. The code below adds the marker but no infowindow shows when I click on a marker, there are no console or browser errors at all, any suggestions?!

Everything works grand except for the infowindow, the only thing I can think of that might be the issue is that the marker needs to be plotted before you can add a listener to it!?

```
var map;
var mapMarkers = [];

function displayMap()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });

    map.setCenter({lat: 40.7127837, lng: -74.00594130000002});
}

function addMarker(lat, lng, icon, infobox) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: icon
    });

    attachMessage(marker, infobox);

    mapMarkers.push(marker);
}

function attachMessage(marker, message) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    });
}

function setMapOnAllmap(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {
        mapMarkers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function clearMarkers() {
    setMapOnAllmap(null);
}

function deleteMarkers() {
    clearMarkers();
    mapMarkers = [];
}

function loadMarkerData(op1, op2, op3)
{
    var data = {id: 1, op1:op1, op2:op2, op3:op3};

    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            deleteMarkers();
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if (data != '') {
                markerObj = eval(data);

                $.each(markerObj, function(index, element) {
                    addMarker(element.lat, element.lng, element.icon, element.infobox)
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

An example of the data returned by the ajax call is:
  `[{"lat":"0.00000000000000","lng":"0.00000000000000","icon":"../marker.png","info":"information for the infobox"}]`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @gepcodezip, the full code I'm using is above, the only thing missing is the data returned, as I've stated in the OT the data is not the issue as it's plotting correctly the markers, thanks for your reponse, I have since figured it out.

Comment: [The code you posted works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/0yzhq6fh/), it doesn't demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip, I appreciate the effort but I'm still having the same issue with the code I posted above, the reason I hadn't got any more information in the OT was that there were no errors either in the server logs, browser console or on screen, the markers plotted fine but the infowindow didn't display when the marker was clicked on, I have been able to get it work with the code in the answer I posted below for anyone else that may come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out by using closure, the code that I was having the problem with where the infowindow was replaced like below and the infowindow is now displaying.

**Current**

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, icon, infobox) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: icon
    });

    attachMessage(marker, infobox);

    mapMarkers.push(marker);
}

function attachMessage(marker, message) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: message
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
    });
}
```

**New - working code**

I created an `infowindow` variable with the `map` and `marker` variables:

```
var map;
var mapMarkers = [];
var infowindow;
```

Initialised `infowindow` in the map loading function:

```
function displayMap()
{
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}
```

Changed `addMarker` function:

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, icon, infobox) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        icon: icon
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow){ 
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
    })(marker, infobox, infowindow));

    mapMarkers.push(marker);
}
```